# how to check if user has permission to delete objects in django

Tags: ajax, django, django-views

I am trying to write a view method that responds to an AJAX request to delete an entry.  I want to check if the end user is the actual author of the Entry before deleting that Entry.  Does my "if" statement accomplish this?

VIEWS.PY

```
latest_entries=Entry.objects.order_by('-pub_date')[:16]

@login_required
def delete_object(request):
   if request.is_ajax():
      object_name = request.POST.get('entryname')
      targetobject = Entry.objects.get(author=object_name)
      if request.user = targetobject.author:
         targetobject.delete() 
      return HttpResponseRedirect('/storefront/')
```

MODELS

```
Class Entry(models.Model):
    author = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    subject = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=30)
```

Comment: if request.user == targetobject.author:   use ==

Comment: if you're on the right path, can;t you test it before asking it?

Comment: Also is your query correct? Entry.objects.get(author=object_name) does not feel right. (If it was, why not do `if request.user == object_name:` in the first place :P)

Answer (score 0):

You're almost there. `request.user` is an instance of `django.utils.SimpleLazyObject`, so you won't be able to do an == comparison of `request.user` to a CharField, of which the value is a string under the covers.

You need to do something like:

```
if request.user.username == targetobject.author:
    targetobject.delete()
```

or just use whatever field from the `User` object is synonymous with `Entry.author`.

Answer (score 0):

I'd say your model is wrong. `author` should be a ForeignKey to the auth.User model. Then your comparison would work (with the change to `==`), and there are other benefits too in terms of grouping and querying by user attributes.

Comment: I just double checked and it actually is ForeignKey to auth.User.model.

Comment: I can't test this right now because I'm away from my work machine, but even without the foreign key, I'm guessing it should work.